# Prolog how to count the number of facts without using a built in

Tags: prolog

Given a number of facts is there a way to count them without using a built in function I have tried doing so with the below code but could no get it work. I hope someone can help me out.
For example the following facts:

```
stops(jubilee,bondstreet,1).
stops(jubilee,waterloo,2).
stops(jubilee,bakerstreet,3).
```

The code have got so far is:

```
findStops(X) :- stops(X,_, N), N1 is N+1, stopsX,_,N1).
```

I would like to make it so that N1 is the counter of how stops the jubilee line has.

Comment: Hint: make a list of results you retrieve, to prevent receiving the same fact twice.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is there a way to add the results recursively?

Comment: You write `N1 is N+1` and thus you are using `(is)/2` which is a built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to count the number of `stops/3` facts that have the atom `jubilee` in the first argument. Assuming all clauses for the `stops/3` predicate have a bound first argument, you could write:

```
?- findall(1, stops(jubilee,_,_), List), length(List, Count).
```

In this query, `findall/3` is a standard Prolog predicate and `length/2` is a de facto standard predicate, usually available as a built-in predicate or as a library predicate.

Can you convert this query into a predicate that takes the station as an argument (instead of a hardcoded station as `jubilee`) and returns the count for that station?

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't totally clear since it hasn't been defined what is allowed in terms of "built in" predicates. Such a problem cannot be solved without using some kind of predefined predicate.

Here are a couple of other ideas.

Using `assertz` and `retract`:

```
count_stops(Count) :-
    assertz(num_stops(0)),
    count_stops_aux(Count).

count_stops_aux(_) :-
    stops(_, _, _),
    retract(num_stops(C)),
    C1 is C + 1,
    assertz(num_stops(C1)),
    fail.
count_stops_aux(Count) :-
    retract(num_stops(Count)).
```

You could also probably do something similar with SWI Prolog's `b_setval/2` and `b_getval/2`.

Here's a recursive solution that uses a list to check whether we've counted a particular fact already:

```
count_stops(Count) :-
    count_stops_aux([], 0, Count).

count_stops_aux(L, Count, Total) :-
    stops(A, B, C),
    \+ member(stops(A,B,C), L),
    C is Count + 1,
    count_stops_aux([stops(A,B,C)|L], C, Total), !.
count_stops_aux(_, Total, Total).
```

Or similarly, but using `length/2` as well:

```
count_stops(Count) :-
    count_stops_aux([], Facts),
    length(Facts, Count).

count_stops_aux(L, Facts) :-
    stops(A, B, C),
    \+ member(stops(A,B,C), L),
    count_stops_aux([stops(A,B,C)|L], Facts), !.
count_stops_aux(Facts, Facts).
```

The first solution will count redundant facts (if an identical fact exists more than once), and `assertz` and `retract` are slow operations. The second and third solutions won't count redundant facts, but are really just clunky, verbose versions of Paulo's solution to avoid using `findall`. This is all why Prolog has predicates such as `findall/3` and `bagof/3`.